# Spark Map Data type Issue

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm having the below issue when selecting from a view using spark. And the view definition has one or more tables with Map data type. How do we handle this?

SQL:

```
select XXX_ID,count(1) as mtrc_value 
FROM GLOBAL.DDM_VW_CPT
WHERE XXX_ID > date_sub(current_date,8) group by XXX_ID
```

Error : Exception Occurred -

> Cannot have map type columns in DataFrame which calls set operations(intersect, except, etc.), but the type of column event_values is map;;

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

`XXX_ID` should be in `group by`:

```
select XXX_ID,count(1) as  mtrc_value 
FROM GLOBAL.DDM_VW_CPT 
WHERE XXX_ID > date_sub(current_date,8) group by XXX_ID
```

Comment: Sorry i already have the query as what you mentioned. But still the same error.